# FTPClient.connect does not work

Tags: android, upload, ftp

I will upload a File via FTP and Android. The problem is that I can not connect to the server.  I use the http://commons.apache.org/ FTP 1.4.1 Libary.

Here is my code:

```
FTPClient ftpClientUp = new FTPClient();

try {
    ftpClientUp.connect(InetAddress.getByName("myftpserver.tld"));
} 

catch (Exception e) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Allways come this message :/" Toast.LENGTH_SHORT), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

And this is the error message I am getting:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you tell us what the message is that comes with the exception?

Comment: The message is: "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Answer (score 1):

You should make network requests in a separate thread (not in main, UI thread). You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).